# Unable to set a breakpoint in IDA 6?

Tags: ida

I am unable to set a breakpoint in IDA 6. I have tried pressing  <kbd>F2</kbd> , but it did not work. Also, the breakpoints buttons on the toolbar are all disabled. What's the problem?

Comment: Also, make sure you have a debugger selected. You need to choose one, e.g. WinDBG, before adding a breakpoint, at least in 6.x.

Answer (score 5):

Not all views of IDA offer breakpoints. You should be able to set breakpoints on certain views, for example `IDA View`. Other views do not offer breakpoints and automatically disable them. Such views include, but not limited to `Hex View`, `Structures`, `Enums`, `Imports`, and `Exports`.

This is how the process of setting breakpoints is described in [IDA-Pro Book](http://nostarch.com/idapro.htm):

> Breakpoints are set in IDA **by navigating to the location** at which you want execution to pause and using the F2 hotkey (or right-clicking and selecting Add Breakpoint). Addresses at which breakpoints have been set are highlighted with a red (by default) band across the entire disassembly line. A breakpoint may be removed by pressing F2 a second time to toggle the breakpoint off. A complete list of breakpoints currently set within a program may be viewed via Debugger->Breakpoints->Breakpoint List.

Answer (score 1):

Also, as a super basic thing to check, verify that you are currently connected to a remote debugger. :)  I've made that mistake before.  Shut down the remote debugger and forgot about it!